# How do i toggle visibility of a threebox line in mapbox?

Tags: three.js, mapbox-gl-js, threebox

I want to be able to toggle the visibility of my 3D line layer in mapbox

Threebox has a method called toggleLayer, however i am not able to add the TB.line to the layer and freely toggle the line layer.

Currently i am generating the lines using (x,y,z) with threebox line method.

I am fairly new to this, so please be kind.